# Generate a random color for every user and keep track of created colors. Every color MUST be different

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my app every user that connects to the server needs to get a random distinct color and I have to keep track of them. About 20 to 30 will be connected in the same time. When a user disconnects, his color gets dismissed.

My question is if I did this correctly concerning performance and thread safety.

```
public class RandomColorGenerator
{
    private static IList<Color> currentColors = new List<Color>();
    private static Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
    private object lockObject = new object();

    public Color GetRandomColor ( )
    {
        var color = Color.FromArgb(random.Next(200, 255), random.Next(150, 255), random.Next(150, 255));
        lock ( lockObject )
        {
            if ( currentColors.Contains(color, new ColorEqualityComparer()) )
                return GetRandomColor();
            else
                {
                    currentColors.Add(color);
                    return color;
                }
        }
    }

    public void DismissRandomColor (Color color)
    {
        lock ( lockObject )
        {
            var tmpColor = currentColors.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.ToArgb() == color.ToArgb());
            currentColors.Remove(tmpColor);
        }
    }
}


public class ColorEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<System.Drawing.Color>
{
    public bool Equals (Color x, Color y) => x.ToArgb() == y.ToArgb();

    public int GetHashCode (Color obj) => obj.GetHashCode();
}
```

EDIT:

Thanks everybody for your help and advices, you helped me a lot about this problem and i have also managed to learn a couple of extra stuff :) Since randomness wasn't really that needed, i will just create about 60 random colors offline and store them in an array or a dictionary and just assign them to users as needed.

Comment: Why does it have to be *random*? Is there some security aspect to the problem, where a user must not be able to predict the colour of another user?  People often talk about randomness as though it was cheap, easy, or the default behaviour, but randomness is actually a very deep property that requires careful engineering to get right.  If you can avoid randomness, do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its important to know how many distinct colours you have available, and how distinct they have to be. For example can one user have "pale yellow" and another user have "slightly paler yellow"?

If you can have many distinct colours, simply generate them using a deterministic algorithm, starting at 0,0,0 and working your way up to 255,255,255 (this gives you 256*256*256 different colours!). If you need colours to be more distinct, you can still use the fixed algorithm but use a large stepping value - eg increment the value by 64 instead of 1 (which gives you 256/64^3 instead or 64 different colours).

Once you have this kind of algorithm you just need to give each user a number. You will have to maintain a list of these numbers but you can either keep a 'boolean array' of each one or simply search through all users looking for the smallest unused number.

Alternatively, calculate the colours offline and store the values in an array. Each user gets an index into that array. For a new user simply look through all users for the next unused index, or store a 'used/free' flag alongside the colour and update the array as users come and go.

Comment: As a suggestion, HSL/V would be a better option than trying to fiddle about with RGB values.

Comment: @JamesSnell makes no difference really - the OP uses Color.FromArgb and we're just using automatic values so I figured that'd be more easily understandable for him.

Comment: I accepted this answer because i chose to listen to the advice to calculate colours offline and store them in an array.

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic cool. Remember also that if you're choosing colours offline, you can manage them to be more friendly to visually-imparied users, possibly have a selection of colours that are more contrasting by hue than colour or even for the admin to choose from different sets of colours such as softer pastel or brighter neon.

Comment: @gbjbaanb: It doesn't make a difference in terms of the approach of number-to-color mapping, but it does make a difference in how simple it is to create distinct colors using sequential numbering. Even if you cycle in steps of 64 in RGB like you suggested, you're going to be using very similar colors (dark shades of either black/darkgrey/darkgreen for a long while). Comparatively, HSL would allow you to immediately vary the color itself, and then later vary the intensity of that color when you need extra colors. Technically the same, but HSL will give you a better _visual_ color variety.

Answer (score 16):

I believe you are making this a bit too hard on yourself - along with the possibility of generating `#ffffff` and `#fffffe` as two "distinct" colors.  However, you won't be able to perceive the difference.

Trying to generate a new color on the fly that is visually distinct from other colors is challenging. Doable, but challenging - especially as the human visual system is non-linear (we are able to distinguish two different greens that are more closely separated than two different reds).

And thus, don't generate random colors on the fly.

Make a list of 50 or 100 (you will have some difficulty when you get to 100) random colors and just use an index into that list.  Each time a color is released, put it back at the end of the list of colors to be allocated.

Related:

- SO: [How to automatically generate N “distinct” colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/470690)
- UX: [How many visually distinct colors can accurately be associated with a separated legend in a figure?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/17964/28531)
- GameDev: [How can I find an optimum set of colors for 10 players?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/46463/62382)

In the UX question, the links within the own experiments are especially interesting:

> I have done [my own](http://phrogz.net/tmp/colordifferences/) [investigations](http://phrogz.net/tmp/24colors.html) [into this](http://phrogz.net/tmp/24colors-plotted.html) and come up with [a page](http://phrogz.net/css/distinct-colors.html) for generating a set of colors with user-specifiable visual separation.

Comment: As a related link, I'd like to add this answer from GameDev SE: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46463/how-can-i-find-an-optimum-set-of-colors-for-10-players

Comment: @Ivan thank you.  That is certainly relevant and useful.  I've added it to the related section.

Answer (score 4):

You asked about thread safety. Absolutely this code is not thread safe. The methods of Random are not documented as being safe to call from multiple threads, and in fact they are not safe. See

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/getting-random-numbers-in-a-thread-safe-way/

for details.

As I said in my comment, consider dropping the randomness requirement. Likely you can get by with some far less onerous requirement.

Comment: Well, since this app is never going to have more than 30-40 simultaneous users, and after reading your linked blog, and other answers in this thread, i'll just create about 60 random colors offline and store them in an array. As you advised, i'll remove randomness and just use the array. Thanks for your help and advice.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `List` and `lock`, I would use [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) with color being Key and value unused (just put some junk in there) (would be nice to have `ConcurrentSet` in .NET) and [TryAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267291(v=vs.110).aspx) and [TryRemove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287129(v=vs.110).aspx) methods. This will get rid of the recursive locking, make things slightly faster and predictable.

Comment: Why not using [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @MainMa Because BlockingCollection is not item-unique. It is just a collection where duplicates are allowed.